# how to make a JavaScript clock as per database values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a analog clock using JavaScript.
Now I have working hours and off hours that come from database.

So I want to show working hours in some color and off hours in another color. How do I do this?

From database I have start time and End time

Eg:

**FROM TIME**:00:00:00

**END TIME** :11:59:00

This is that clock :[Clock](https://jsfiddle.net/02mgq2yn/)

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
style="background-color:Blue">
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an API like this for the drawClock function?

```
drawClock(currentTime, offHours)


function isOffHours() {
  // Always working
  return false
}
setInterval(function() {
  drawClock(new Date(), isOffHours())
}, 1000)
```

This way the clock drawing function itself doesn't get to decide what time it is, the rendering part of the app is better off being unaware.

This would require you to change the signature of the drawTime function too:

```
drawTime(ctx, radius, time) {
  var hour = time.getHours();
  var minute = time.getMinutes();
  var second = time.getSeconds();
  ...
}
```

EDIT: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gf8g8790/2/

Comment: My Knowledge of javascript is not this good so i dont know how i will be able to use this

Comment: Hello @Rajan check this: https://jsfiddle.net/gf8g8790/1/
for an example on how to make this work. You still have to find a way to get the on/off hours from your database onto the web page though. Hope that helps.

Comment: So will the colors change after some time  ??? and it was just for example lets say from 7:00 am to 5:00 pm working hours and 5:00 to next day 6:59 are off hours something like this

Comment: Now the colors will change if time goes past 7:00 am or 4:59 pm
https://jsfiddle.net/gf8g8790/2/